# Limiting the size of a picked file using an input with dataType File

Tags: opus-ui

I have an Input with dataType File that we are using to capture an image , i want to limit the max size of the picked file to limit any network related issues associated with a user saving a larger then intended file

tried using the length of the value of the file however doing so i will need to cater for the additional increase in size when converting the image to a base64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by accessing the size property on the file and the "isGreaterThan" operator comparison.

```json
{
    "type": "input",
    "prps": {
        "dataType": "file",
        "scps": [
            {
                "triggers": [
                    {
                        "event": "onStateChange",
                        "key": "file"
                    }
                ],
                "actions": [
                    {
                        "type": "setVariable",
                        "name": "fileSizeInMb",
                        "value": "{{eval. {{state.self.file.size}} / 1024 ** 2 }}"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "applyComparison",
                        "operator": "isGreaterThan",
                        "value": "{{variable.fileSizeInMb}}",
                        "compareValue": 2,
                        "branch": {
                            "true": [
                                {
                                    "type": "log",
                                    "msg": "File size is greater than 2mb"
                                }
                            ],
                            "false": [
                                {
                                    "type": "log",
                                    "msg": "File size is less than 2mb"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Note, this example calculates the file size in megabytes. Read more here:

https://w3collective.com/restrict-file-size-javascript/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Exponentiation